# Combining two fields

Tags: qlikview

in one of my charts I have Branch as the dimension and the expressions are a set of KPIs. I also have a Year (2009-2016) list box that is set up to always have one selected value.

From 2014 onwards I need to amalgamate Branch A into Branch B while leaving the other Branches as they were. My searches so far lead me to believe that a calculated dimension might solve my problem but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Ideally I would like my other charts to continue to display the branches separately. Any advice is appreciated.

-Brandon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go with calculated dimensions and type something like this:

```
if( Year => 2014 and Branch = 'A', 'B', Branch)
```

But my advice is to use calculated dimensions only if there is no other way. Calculated dimensions are nice to have but they lead to performance issues. They are creating additional tables/fields in the memory and if you have decent amount of data this will slow down the calculations.

Instead you can create an additional field in the script (using the same expression) and use this field as dimension in your object.